# Is $f(X)f^d(X) = 0$ for a Boolean function $f$?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, boolean-complexity

I'm currently trying to understand a step in the proof for in the [Crama and Hammer book on Boolean Functions](https://doc.lagout.org/science/0_Computer%20Science/2_Algorithms/Boolean%20Functions_%20Theory%2C%20Algorithms%2C%20and%20Applications%20%5BCrama%20%26%20Hammer%202011-05-16%5D.pdf). The proof is Proposition 4.12, which claims that the self-dualization of Boolean $f$ is bijective.

The specific statement that I am confused about is a step showing that:

$$f^d(X)f(X) \lor f(X) \bar{x}_{n+1} \lor f^d(X) {x}_{n+1} = f(X) \bar{x}_{n+1} \lor f^d(X) {x}_{n+1}.$$

Here $f(X)$ is a d-dimensional Boolean function, $X = (x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n) \in \mathcal{B}^n$, and $f^d(X) := \overline{f(\overline{X})}$ is the *dual* of $f$.

This equality above seems to require that $f^d(X)f(X) = 0.$ I am wondering why this is? I think that I am missing something simple, or maybe I've found a typo in the proof. If someone has a different proof for the broader claim that self-dualization is bijective, that would be fine.

---

I've copied the full proposition below in case it helps:

[image: Proposition 4.12]

Here $f^{SD}(X)$ is the *self-dual extension* of $f$. This is a function over the (d+1)-dimensional Boolean hypercube such that $$f^{SD}(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n, x_{n+1}) = f(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)\bar{x}_{n+1} \lor f^d(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)\bar{x}_{n+1}.$$

Comment: Your question is hard to answer without the requisite definitions. What is $f^d$? What is $f^{SD}$?

Comment: Dual for conjunction is disjunction, but both are true for true arguments.

Comment: please edit your question and put the definitions into the text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$f^d(X)f(X) \lor f(X) \bar{x}_{n+1} \lor f^d(X) {x}_{n+1} = f(X) \bar{x}_{n+1} \lor f^d(X) {x}_{n+1}$$
The equality above comes from the general equality below. It has nothing to do with the context.

$\begin{aligned}
&\quad\ yz\lor  y\overline{x_{n+1}} \lor z{x}_{n+1}\\
&=yz(\overline{x_{n+1}} \lor x_{n+1})\lor  y\bar{x}_{n+1} \lor z{x}_{n+1}\\
&=(yz\overline{x_{n+1}} \lor yzx_{n+1})\lor  y\bar{x}_{n+1} \lor z{x}_{n+1}\\
&=(yz\overline{x_{n+1}}\lor y\bar{x}_{n+1})\lor (yzx_{n+1}\lor z{x}_{n+1})\\
&=y\bar{x}_{n+1}\lor z{x}_{n+1}\\
\end{aligned}$